# Commitizen Non Interactive is bringing up interactive mode

Tags: commitizen

I am able to use commitizen with interactive mode as expected. However in non-interactive mode is not functioning.

```
git-cz --non-interactive --type=feat --subject="add onClick prop to component"
cz-cli@4.2.3, cz-conventional-changelog@3.3.0

? Select the type of change that you're committing: (Use arrow keys)
❯ feat:     A new feature 
  fix:      A bug fix 
  docs:     Documentation only changes 
  style:    Changes that do not affect the meaning of the code (white-space, formatting, missing semi-colons, etc) 
  refactor: A code change that neither fixes a bug nor adds a feature 
  perf:     A code change that improves performance 
  test:     Adding missing tests or correcting existing tests 
(Move up and down to reveal more choices)
```

What could be going wrong here?
Ref : https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-cz

Answer (score 0):

The --non-interactive syntax is supported by another library git-cz (https://github.com/streamich/git-cz).

Weirdly enough commitizen (https://github.com/commitizen/cz-cli) also has the same keyword "git-cz" but unfortunately it does not support non-interactive mode yet!